# how to integrate webpack with the existing react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react project and I want to bundle it using webpack. I have set up the entry, output, path, and filename etc,. But, doing so, when I am running the project I get the following errors. How can I solve this.

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.42.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
>   higher up in the tree:
>
> C:\Users\gowtham\Desktop\task\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.42.1)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
>   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
>   permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if C:\Users\gowtham\Desktop\task\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
>   We hope you find them helpful!
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! task@0.1.0 start:
>   `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! Failed at the
>   task@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\gowtham\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-09T11_57_57_611Z-debug.log

PS C:\Users\gowtham\Desktop\task> npm start

> > task@0.1.0 start C:\Users\gowtham\Desktop\task
> >     react-scripts start
>
> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.42.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
>   higher up in the tree:
>
> C:\Users\gowtham\Desktop\task\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.42.1)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
>   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
>   permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if C:\Users\gowtham\Desktop\task\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
>   We hope you find them helpful!
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! task@0.1.0 start:
>   `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
>   at the task@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\gowtham\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-09T11_59_28_082Z-debug.log

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you... read the steps described? Or try them?

Comment: I read, but I don't understand it cause I'm doing it the first time

Comment: "To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:" – do those things.